# How do I highlight a specific part of a DIV using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and jQuery 1.7.

Assume that my page is completely covering the div width 100% and height 100%.

i just want to select a specific part and change the CSS of that part, for example, highlight it with a different color.

I want to highlight a specific part of the DIV using jQuery

Please help me out !!!!

**Update**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
behind the whole html of the page this 
div overlay's the html tag
<div Style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index:100000;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want select the text like bugmuncher.com

Comment: Please post a (small) code sample showing how your HTML is laid out.

Comment: You'll need to wrap it in a `<span>` for sure, unless it's all on one line, in which case you can use a gradient and should use a `<span>` anyways.

Comment: Try this  >> http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/jquery-complete-beginners-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

To perform a highlight to a certain div id or class.

```
$('#id').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
```

Make sure you wrap the specific code with a span tag.

```
Your sentence with a <span id="id">highlighted</span> part.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the [jquery hilighter plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html). Simple to use.